# How to scynhronise read_handler calls of sock.async_read_some to a specific frequency?

Tags: c++, boost, client, boost-asio

How to scynhronise read_handler calls of sock.async_read_some to a specific frequency, while reading streams of 812 bytes (which is streamed with 125 Hz frequency).

I have a problem related with reading a stream from a robot. I am very new to the boost asio. And I have very little info on this concept. Here is a sample block from my code. What the read_handler does is, it processes the data coming from robot. This loop should execute at every 8 ms which is my sampling time and also by the time it starts to execute, reading of the data stream from the robot should be completed. When I look at the robot's stream data, data comes at each 8 ms. So the robot data is OK. But the execution of read_handler is somehow problematic. for instance, one loop starts at time =0, second loop starts at time=2, third loop starts at time = 16, forth loop starts at time=18, and fifth loop again starts at time = 32. So, the triggering time of the loop changes from every first time to second time. But on the third it syncronizes again to a multiple of 8 ms. What I need is read_handler should trigger at every 8 ms (when the data arrives) but it catches this sampling time at every two calls (total of 16 ms). This is crucial since I am making computations, and feeding a command back to robot later on (A control system). This code segment is not detailed with sending commands etc, this segment only contains very basic data processes.
So, what might be causing these variations between calls, and how can I fix it?

I searched through the net and stack overflow but I couldn't run into another time related issue as I faced.

```
void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{

    if (!ec)
    {
        thisLoopStart = clock();
        loopInstant[iterationNum]=diffclock(startTime, endLoopTime);
        std::cout << "Byte transfered: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
        printf("Byte transfered: %d", bytes_transferred);
        printf("Byte transfered: %d", bytes_transferred);
        printf("Byte transfered: %d\n", bytes_transferred);
        //std::cout << std::string(buffer.data(), bytes_transferred) << std::endl;
        char myTempDoubleTime[8];
        for (int j = 0; j<1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
            {
                myTempDoubleTime[7-i]=buffer[4+i+8*j]; //636
            }
            memcpy(&controllerTime[iterationNum], myTempDoubleTime, 8);
        }
        endLoopTime = clock();

        thisLoopDuration = diffclock(thisLoopStart, endLoopTime);

        loopTimes[iterationNum] = thisLoopDuration;

        if (iterationNum++>500)
        {//io_service.~io_service();

            //io_service.reset();
            //io_service.run();
            exitThread = 1;
            printf("Program terminates...\n");
            GlobalObjects::myFTSystem->StopAcquisition();

            for(int i=1;i<iterationNum;i++)
                fprintf(LoopDurations, "%f\t%f\t%f\n", loopTimes[i], controllerTime[i], loopInstant[i]);


            fclose(LoopDurations);

            closeConnectionToServer();
            printf("Connection is closed...\n");
            io_service.stop();
        }
        sock.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), read_handler);    
    }

}
```

Comment: either use `deadline_timer` or run `poll()` at specific intervals

Comment: Could you be more specific? How can I do that, and how does it do? I am not an experienced user. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the incoming stream timing is controlled by the robot itself, then you shouldn't be worrying about trying to read specifically at such and such time. If you're expecting a burst of 812 bytes from the robot every X seconds, simply keep async_reading from your client socket. boost::asio will invoke your callback as soon as the read is complete.

As for your mysterious delay, try explicitly stating the size of your buffer in your call to async_read_some like so:

```
sock.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 812), read_handler);
```

If you're sure you're always transmitting enough data to fill such a buffer, then this should cause your callback to be invoked consistently because the buffer supplied to boost::asio is full. If this doesn't solve your problem, then do as sehe suggested and implement a [dealine_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) that you can use to have finer time-based control over your asynchronous ops.

**Edit**

You should also be checking the bytes_transferred in your OnRead handler to ensure that you've made a complete read from the robot. Right now you're just printing it. You could have an incomplete read which means you should immediately start reading again repeatedly from the socket until you're sure you've consumed all of the data you're expecting. Otherwise, you're going to screw yourself up by trying to act on incomplete data, most likely failing there, then starting up another `::async_read` assuming you're starting a clean new read when really you're just going to read old data you ignored and left on the socket, and begin fragmenting your reads.

This could explain why you're seeing inconsistent times that are both shorter and longer than your expected interval. Explicitly specifying buffer size and checking the bytes_transferred that you're passed in the handler will guarantee that you catch such a problem. Also look at docs for completion_condition types you can pass to ::asio such as `::transfer_exactly(num_bytes)`, but I'm not sure if those apply to async read ops.